# Conexion Eclipse con Sql Server: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed

Tags: java, eclipse

Estoy tratando hace un tiempo de conectar mi base de datos de `SQL SERVER` utilizando Server Management Studio y no lo he logrado, en la consola siempre me sale este error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:285)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2462)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:668)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2695)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2362)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2213)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1276)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:861)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
    at JDBC.ConectaGestion.main(ConectaGestion.java:20)
```

1. He verificado en mi windows 10 que mi conexion TCP/IP en SQL Server 2019 Configuration Manager esta habilitada y en el puerto 1433
2. Añadi a mi firewall el puerto 1433

Este es mi codigo en Java. Alguno sabe que puede ser?

````
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

       try {
           
           Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
           
           String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
                                   + "databaseName = CentroMedico;"
                                   + "user = sa;"
                                   + "password = 1234";
                                   
           //1: CREAR CONEXION         
           Connection miCon = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
           
           //2: CREAR STATEMENT
           Statement miSt = miCon.createStatement();
           
           //3: EJECUTAR INSTRUCCION SQL
           ResultSet miRs = miSt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Paciente");
           
           //4: LEER EL RESULSET
           while(miRs.next()) {
               System.out.println(miRs.getString(1));
           }
           
           
           
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }```
````

Comment: hecha una ojeada a esto talvez sirve de algo http://acodigo.blogspot.com/2013/06/conectar-sql-server-con-java.html

Comment: Hice todos los pasos tal cual y nada!